# How can I convert a PDF into a series of Images (JPGs or PNGs) via the terminal on mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, pdf, image-conversion

I have a pdf

and I'd like to convert it to a series of images, numbered `0001.jpg` - `XXXX.jpg` ?

I found this so far

`sips -s format png your_pdf_file.pdf --out your_png_file.png`

but it seems to only to the first page of the pdf, and the quality of the outputted png seems not so good. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the club )) Try [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/)

Comment: Wrote this article with the purpose of answering a similar question https://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2019/08/how-to-convert-pdf-document-into-Powerpoint-slides.html I will also post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `ghostscript` which is not preinstalled on every Mac (that is what ImageMagick uses under the hood). You have to install it separately.

```bash
gs -dSAFER -dQUIET -dNOPLATFONTS -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \ 
  # When converting multiple-page PDFs you should add "%d" to the filename-string 
  # which will be replaced with the sequence-number of the file
  -sOutputFile="outputFileName" \ 
  # Create a PNG-File with alpha-transparency
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha
  # resolution in DPI
  -r72 \ 
  # Use high grade text antialiasing. Can be 0, 1, 2 or 4
  -dTextAlphaBits=4 \
  # Use high grade graphics anti-aliasing. Can be 0, 1, 2 or 4
  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
  # If you are converting a CMYK-PFD to RGB-color you should use CIE-Color
  -dUseCIEColor \
  # use the PDFs Trim-Box to define the final image
  -dUseTrimBox \
  # start converting on the first side of the PDF
  -dFirstPage=1 \
  # convert only until the first page of the PDF
  -dLastPage=1 \
  # Path to the file you want to convert
  InputFile.pdf
```

For more information on how to use the CLI-Parameters, have a look at [Using Ghostscript](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html)

Comment: thank you so much. I get a `FC_WEIGHT didn't match` (?)

Comment: From what I read at https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ghostscript-problem-april-2019/81385/4 it looks as though your PDF file uses a font that is neither embedded in the PDF nor is available on the font path. so the PDF file is faulty. To fix the problem you can add the path to the location of the font files using `-sFONTPATH=/path/to/fontfilesfolder`

Comment: To find out which font that might be have a look at the font-info in your PDF and watch outnfor fonts not marked as "embedded" or "partially embedded"

Comment: I just realized that you could possibly remove the `-dNOPLATFONTS` to solve the FC_WEIGHT issue.

Answer (score 11):

### ImageMagick

The easiest way is to [use ImageMagick](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/imagemagick). Install ImageMagick if you haven't already

```
brew install imagemagick --with-fontconfig --with-ghostscript --with-openjpeg --with-webp
```

Convert the PDF document into a series of images

```
convert -quality 100 -density 200 -colorspace sRGB "The_Artificial_Intelligence_Crush_2018.pdf" -flatten output-%02d.jpg
```

[More details on producing sharp, high-quality image using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605085/399759).

### Ghostscript

ImageMagick uses Ghostscript in the background to perform the PDF conversion. So why not use Ghostscript directly?

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r200 -dJPEGQ=100 -sOutputFile=document-%02d.jpg "The_Artificial_Intelligence_Crush_2018.pdf" -dBATCH
```

#### Reference

[Convert PDF to image with high resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605006/convert-pdf-to-image-with-high-resolution/6605085#6605085)
[How to convert multi-page PDF to images in command line](https://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-convert-multi-page-pdf-to-images-in-command-line.html)
[How to convert a PDF document into Powerpoint slides](https://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2019/08/how-to-convert-pdf-document-into-Powerpoint-slides.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `convert` ( [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) ) to parse `PDF` files.

### PNG output

Convert `test.pdf` to numbered `PNG` images:

`convert -density 150 -trim test.pdf page%d.png`

### JPEG output

Convert `test.pdf` to numered `JPEG` images:

`convert -density 150 -trim test.pdf -quality 100 -flatten -sharpen 0x1.0 page%d.jpg`

As per @JBWhitmore's explanation from his great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605085/5720818)):

```sh
convert                  \
   -verbose              \
   -density 150          \
   -trim                 \
    <your-PDF-file>.pdf  \
   -quality 100          \
   -flatten              \
   -sharpen 0x1.0        \
    page%d.{png,pdf}
```

> It results in [**the left image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmLXI.jpg). Compare this to the result of my original command ([**the image on the right**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCjw6.jpg)):

[image]  [image]

> (To ***really*** see and appreciate the differences between the two, right-click on each and select *"Open Image in New Tab..."*.)
>
> Also keep the following facts in mind:
>
> - The worse, blurry image on the right has a file size of 1.941.702 Bytes (1.85 MByte). Its resolution is 3060x3960 pixels, using 16-bit RGB color space.
> - The better, sharp image on the left has a file size of 337.879 Bytes (330 kByte). Its resolution is 758x996 pixels, using 8-bit Gray color space.
>
> So, no need to resize; add the `-density` flag. The density value 150 is weird -- trying a range of values results in a worse looking image in both directions!

Comment: can you explain what exactly I am supposed to write in the last line, where you've written `<0001-XXX page numbers>.png` ? I've tried `output_%d.png` but this didn't work.

Comment: use `page-%d.png` to number images

Answer (score -2):

just rename sample.pdf to sample.zip and then unzip sample.zip - it will create a folder with the images